# Alternative to Regex for large string format/replace

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a very large string of key value pairs (old_string) that is formatted as so:

```
"visitorid"="gh43k9sk-gj49-92ks-jgjs-j2ks-j29slgj952ks", "customer_name"="larry", "customer_state"="alabama",..."visitorid"="..."
```

this string is very large since it can be up to 30k customers. I am using this to write a file to upload to an online segmentation tool that requires that it is formatted this way with one modification -- the primary key (visitorid) needs to be tab separated and not in quotes. The end result needs to look like this (note the 4 spaces is a tab):

```
gh43k9sk-gj49-92ks-jgjs-j2ks-j29slgj952ks    "customer_name"="larry", "customer_state"="alabama",...ABC3k9sk-gj49-92ks-dgjs-j2ks-j29slgj9bbbb
```

I wrote the following function that does this fine, but ive noticed that this portion of the script runs the slowest (I am assuming because regex is generally slow).

```
def getGUIDS(old_string):
    '''
    Finds guids in the string and formats it as PK for syncfile
    @param old_string the string created from the nested dict
    @return old_string_fmt the formatted version
    '''

    print ('getting ids')
    ids = re.findall('("\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}",)', cat_string) #looks for GUID based on regex

    for element in ids:
      new_str = str(element.strip('"').strip('"').strip(",").strip('"') + ('\t'))
      old_string_fmt = old_string.replace(element, new_str)


    return old_string_fmt
```

Is there a way this can be done without regex that might speed this up?

Comment: Let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is wrong: you match all occurrences meeting your regex and then replace all occurrences with modified matches. You may simply use `re.sub` to find all non-overlapping matches and replace them with what you need.

See this [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lbgXen):

```
import re

def getGUIDS(old_string):
    '''
    Finds guids in the string and formats it as PK for syncfile
    @param old_string the string created from the nested dict
    @return old_string_fmt the formatted version
    '''
    print ('getting ids')
    return re.sub(r'"\w+"="(\w{8}(?:-\w{4}){4}-\w{12})"(?:,|$)', '\\1\t', old_string) #looks for GUID based on regex

s='"visitorid"="gh43k9sk-gj49-92ks-jgjs-j2ks-j29slgj952ks", "customer_name"="larry", "customer_state"="alabama",..."visitorid"="..."'
print(getGUIDS(s))
# => getting ids
# => gh43k9sk-gj49-92ks-jgjs-j2ks-j29slgj952ks   "customer_name"="larry", "customer_state"="alabama",..."visitorid"="..."
```

I added `"\w+"=` at the start of the regex to also match the key of the GUID value to remove it, replaced a `,` at the end with `(?:,|$)` to match either a `,` or end of string (to also handle cases when the key-value is the last one in the string) and enclosed the part you need to keep with capturing parentheses.

The replacement is a backreference to the capturing group #1 and a tab char.